# popen performance in C

Tags: c, performance, system, popen

I'm designing a program I plan to implement in C and I have a question about the best way (in terms of performance) to call external programs. The user is going to provide my program with a filename, and then my program is going to run another program with that file as input. My program is then going to process the output of the other program.

My typical approach would be to redirect the other program's output to a file and then have my program read that file when it's done. However, I understand I/O operations are quite expensive and I would like to make this program as efficient as possible.

I did a little bit of looking and I found the `popen` command for running system commands and grabbing the output. How does the performance of this approach compare to the performance of the approach I just described? Does `popen` simply write the external program's output to a temporary file, or does it keep the program output in memory?

Alternatively, is there another way to do this that will give better performance?

Comment: what is the relative performance of the reading and writing steps?  does the external process generate results faster than you can process them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Unix systems, `popen` will pass data through an in-memory pipe. Assuming the data isn't swapped out, it won't hit disk. This should give you just about as good performance as you can get without modifying the program being invoked.

Comment: if the process that analyzes the data is much slower than the process that generates data, then the pipe solution is worse

Comment: @Foo, not necessarily - if the program creating the data is _always_ faster, then the slower program will never catch up, so it'll still end up finishing more or less at the same time.

Comment: @Foo Bah: Not often worse than writing to a seperate file, then processing it.  Even if the writer blocks, the processing side may well have a constant supply of data and can start as soon as the writing side has something to write.  That's good.  That the writing side works in a series of short bursts typically doesn't hurt overall elapsed time, nor total CPU usage.

Comment: Imagine a bursty writer in a scenario where every single message must be processed.  If you have the writer write to a pipe, then either stdout is buffered [in which case the writer will block, reducing the performance of the writer] or stdout is unbuffered [in which case messages will be dropped].  Writing to a shared memory segment, however, alleviates both problems.  It is slower than pipe, sure, but in some contexts it is better.

Comment: shared memory segments aren't any better - there's still only a certain maximum buffer space. Pipes also do buffer a certain amount of data (you won't lose data).

Comment: the maximum buffer space in 2.6 linux kernel is 64K if i recall correctly -- check the linux header linux/pipe_fs_i.h  The buffer space for shared memory segments is orders of magnitude larger.

Comment: @Foo The maximum is, yes. But in any case, using shmem requires modifying the program in question, so it's not really a direct comparison. And the receiving program can always spool into its own buffer of whatever size it wants in a separate thread!

Comment: @bdonlan writing to /dev/shm does not require changing the code -- also the whole concept of using popen requires changing the code  :)

Comment: @Foo, writing to /dev/shm isn't shared memory - it's just a ram disk :) and popen need only involve changes to the receiving (invoking) application, is my point.

Comment: @bdonlan in some distros [in particular debian and RHEL], /dev/shm is treated the same way as shared memory (i.e. a call to shm_open will create / read from a stub on the /dev/shm mountpoint, and all of the shared memory syscalls treat both similarly).  Unless you have a different meaning for shared memory?  writing to /dev/shm only requires that the writer's output is redirected to a file there.

Comment: That's correct, /dev/shm is how they implement shared memory - by mmapping a file on a ramdisk. However if you just open a file in /dev/shm and write to it, it's _just a ramdisk_.

Comment: Gotta love the trolling, writing "then the pipe solution is worse [than writing to a file and reading it back]", and then switching to talk about  shared memory, and then to /dev/shm.

Answer (score 2):

popen does pretty much what you are asking for: it does the pipe-fork-exec idiom and gives you a file pointer that you can read and write from.

However, there is a limitation on the size of the pipe buffer (~4K iirc), and if you arent reading quickly enough, the other process could block.

Do you have access to shared memory as a mount point? [on linux systems there is a /dev/shm mountpoint]

Answer (score 2):

1) `popen` keep the program output in memory. It actually uses pipes to transfer data between the processes.

2) `popen` looks IMHO as the best option for performance.

It also have an advantage over files of reducing latency. I.e. your program will be able to get the other program output on the fly, while it is produced. If this output is large, then you don't have to wait until the other program is finished to start processing its output.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with having your subcommand redirect to a file is that it's potentially insecure while `popen` communication can't be intercepted by another process. Plus you need to make sure the filename is unique if you're running several instances of your master program (and thus of your subcommand). The `popen` solution doesn't suffer from this.

The performance of `popen` is just fine as long as your don't read/write one byte chunks. Always read/write multiples of 512 (like 4096). But that does apply to file operations as well. `popen` connects your process and the child process through pipes, so if you don't read then the pipe fills up and the child can't write and vice versa. So all the exchanged data is in memory, but it's only small amounts.

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming Unix or Linux)

Writing to the temp file may be slow if the file is on a slow disk. It also means the entire output will have to fit on the disk.

`popen` connects to the other program using a pipe, which means that output will be sent to your program incrementally. As it is generated, it is copied to your program chunk-by-chunk.